# Why this variety is non-normal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

According to Shafarevich, the "simplest possible example of a non-normal variety" is the curve $ X $ defined by $ y^{2} = x^{2}+x^{3}. $

Why is this variety non-normal? Furthermore, why is it the simplest possible non-normal variety?

Every nonsingular variety is normal, but I don't see how this helps me since $ X $ is singular.

Comment: $V(u^3-v^2)$ is singular at $(0,0)$ with coordinate ring $k[u,v]/(u^3-v^2)= k[t^2,t^3] \subset k[t]$ it is not normal because $t=0$ is a singular point : there is no regular function with a simple zero at $t=0$ whereas it is there in the function field $k(t)$.

Yours is also a curve singular  at $(0,0)$ : $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2) = k[ t(t^2-1),t^2-1]$ and its problem is that it has no function vanishing at $t=1$ but not at $t=-1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a variation on the comment of reuns, let me explain why this curve isn't normal just using the definiton, without mentioning anything about Serre's criterion (which I consider to be more advanced).

The coordinate ring of your curve is $$R:= \frac{k[x,y]}{\left< y^2-x^2-x^3\right>}$$

Now the field of fractions of this ring contains the element $f=\frac{y}{x}$ which is integral over $R$, since it satisfies the equation
$$f^2-x-1=0.$$

On the other hand, you can check that $f$ itself does not belong to $R$. So $R$ is not integrally closed.

(Geometrically you can think of $f$ as giving the slope of the line joining the origin to a given point. Since the curve has two branches passing through the origin with distinct tangent lines, there is no way to extend $f$ to the origin.)

As for why this is the "simplest": well, it's a 1-dimensional variety defined by a single equation of degree 3. (If the degree were 1 or 2, such a variety would be nonsingular, hence normal.)  The only other reasonable candidate I can think of for "simplest" would be the cuspidal curve $y^2=x^3$.

Answer (score 1):

A variety is normal iff it equals its normalization. In dimension $1$, normalization is a resolution of singularities. Thus normal also implies non-singular in the case of curves. You can see that by using Serre's criterion for normality.

The general rule is: ”Normal varieties are regular in codim $1.$“ That means for example, that surfaces do not contain singular curves, only singular points.

Comment: Minor nitpick--smooth is a relative term. What you want to say is `regular'.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks!